# Printing tibble character variable appears with quotation marks

Tags: r, tibble

When I read in a file I couldn't work out why two similar `character` variables were printing differently using `tibble` - one with quotation marks and the other one without. After a bit of digging, I noticed that one contained trailing white space and the other one didn't.

**Is white space the only reason why a `character` variable would be printed with quotation marks?** I can't see any reference to this behaviour on the `tibble` [site](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/).

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(a = c("hjhjh", "popopo"), d = c(1, 2))
df
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   a          d
#   <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 hjhjh      1
# 2 popopo     2

df_with_space <- tibble(a = c("hjhjh ", "popopo"), d = c(1, 2))
df_with_space
#quotation marks:
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   a            d
#   <chr>    <dbl>
# 1 "hjhjh "     1
# 2 "popopo"     2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*tibble* uses [pillar](https://pillar.r-lib.org/index.html) for printing options, compare:

```
> pillar::pillar("abc")
<pillar>
<chr>
abc  

> pillar::pillar(" def")
<pillar>
<chr> 
" def"
```

> As of tibble 3.1.0, printing is handled entirely by the pillar package.

Comment: thanks! I still don't explicitly see in the documentation (`?pillar`) when quotation marks are added...I suppose we can assume its only when leading and trailing white space is present?

Comment: @user63230 yes, I'd assume so, too. Maybe submit an issue at GitHub.